# SMTP server response: 501 Must specify to address &lt;address&gt;

Tags: php, email, smtp

Cannot understand why I am getting this error - both to & from email addresses are valid (I use them daily) so cannot figure out how this is happening - any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: This is working in production but is throwing errors in dev. I have stricter config in dev.
NOTE: I am testing locally on PC using smtp4dev

```
    $to = 'myemail@mydomain.com.au';
    $cc = 'myemail@mydomain.com.au';
    $from = 'myemail@mydomain.com.au';
    $filename = 'Invoice#'.$order_id.'.pdf';
    $message = file_get_contents(ROOT_DIR.'admin/include/email-body.html');
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdf_file));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'To: '. $to . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: '. $cc . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '. $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= "--".$uid."--";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
      print "SUCCESS";
    } else {
      print "FALIED";
    }
```

Here is the result if I print the variables on the mail() line:

```
mail(<myemail@mydomain.com.au>, Company - Invoice#12451, "",
MIME-Version: 1.0 
To: <myemail@mydomain.com.au> 
Cc:
From: Customer Service <myemail@mydomain.com.au> 
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="2c88ff549e67c83e7a6e3df0bffe9dc9"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--2c88ff549e67c83e7a6e3df0bffe9dc9 Content-type:text/html;
charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

---> html message body stripped <---


--2c88ff549e67c83e7a6e3df0bffe9dc9 Content-Type: application/pdf;
name="Invoice#12451.pdf" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Invoice#12451.pdf"

--> pdf attachment stripped <--


--2c88ff549e67c83e7a6e3df0bffe9dc9--)
```

Comment: You might want to compose and send your mails with something like http://swiftmailer.org/ instead of string concatenation/mail(). It really makes email related things a lot smoother.

Comment: Try adding reply-to header as well.

Comment: Darhazer: that's a red herring.  The Reply-To: header is completely optional, and certainly doesn't affect the acceptability of the envelope `RCPT TO`.

Comment: If smtp4dev is not RFC-compliant, it might require the To: header to be in <brokets>, like it says in the error message.

Comment: $to and $from were originally in brackets. Removed them as I thought this might be the issue - just replaced them and no effect - still getting same error - so the error is not really helping!

Comment: Second what @VolkerK said. [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) is great. No sense reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @tripleee (Author of smtp4dev here) I believe smtp4dev IS RFC compliant in this respect as it requires the address submitted to the RCPT TO command to be surrounded in <brokets>: (see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-3.3)

Comment: @rnwood: Sure, I was speculating that it would require the RFC5322 "To:" header to be in the same format (maybe it would just copy the header verbatim to the envelope) but that seems a far shot.  Now that you are here, maybe you can confirm that this is not the problem.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the hint about php copying the headers to the envelope, that is indeed the case - see edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Author of smtp4dev here)

This is an updated answer - I couldn't originally reproduce the problem with the code you posted, but I noticed that your second bit of output shows that sometimes you don't have a CC address.

This code reproduces the problem and results in the 501 error.

```
<?php
    $to = 'myemail@mydomain.com.au';   
    $cc = '';  
    $from = 'myemail@mydomain.com.au';
    $headers .= 'To: '. $to . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: '. $cc . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '. $from . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

On Windows the PHP mail function looks at the message headers for TO/CC addresses and converts each header to a SMTP RCPT TO command. Unfortunately it does this even if the header has no value:

```
220 localhost smtp4dev ready
HELO Computer
250 Nice to meet you
MAIL FROM:<myemail@mydomain.com.au>
250 Okey dokey
RCPT TO:<myemail@mydomain.com.au>
250 Recipient accepted
RCPT TO:<>
501 Must specify to address <address>
QUIT
221 See you later aligator
```

The fix is therefore is that you need to not include the CC: header at all if you don't have a CC address to send to:

```
<?php
    $to = 'myemail@mydomain.com.au';   
    $cc = '';  
    $from = 'myemail@mydomain.com.au';
    $headers .= 'To: '. $to . "\r\n";

    if ($cc) {
        $headers .= 'Cc: '. $cc . "\r\n";
    }
    $headers .= 'From: '. $from . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

This worked fine for me.

Comment: You are the man!  I actually fixed this but I never figured out how...  ended up removing the $to, $cc and $from and using the $to in the mail() call (instead of within the additional headers), adding the $from into php.ini and concatenating the $cc to the $to is it existed...  Now you've explained it, that is clearly what the issue was!

Comment: While i've got you - can you help with blank emails in smtp4dev? if i view message source, the content is there AND if i send through external, live smtp server it displays fine, it just wont display in smtp4dev mail viewer window. It has html body with pdf attachment - any restrictions in smtp4dev?

Comment: @tripleee - I know how it works- thanks for being so condescending! I don't want SO to help - I want the smtp4dev author's feedback

Answer (score 2):

smtp4dev is just a bit pickier than most actual SMTP relays with regard to the format of the recipient.

Doesn't work:

```
helo me
mail from: me@here.com
rcpt to: somebody@mydomain.tld
```

Works:

```
helo me
mail from: me@here.com
rcpt to: <somebody@mydomain.tld>
```